# Aligning a div's width with previous/next containers

Tags: html, css

I want to create a form thats width is orientied by the form fields. My form has some explaining text and form fields mixed. Each contained in an div with inline-block set.

The outer div (also with inline-block) should NOT get wider than needed by the form fields. That should also be true, if the explaining text is wider than the form fields.

- At design time I don't know the width of the widest form field
- The width of the form fields can change after the form is displayed
- I'm looking for a CSS only solution (no JS please!)
- The #outer or any of the divs should NOT get a fixed with

First of all, here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SuperNova3000/PqJk6/

## Markup

```
<div id="outer">
    <div class="text">
        Explaining Text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="text1">Edit #1</label>
        <input type="text" size="25" id="text1" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Some more text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label for="text2">Edit #2</label>
        <input type="text" size="35" id="text2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

## Styling

```
div { display: inline-block; padding: 10px; }
#outer { border: black 10px solid; }
.text { background-color: red; }
.field { background-color: green; }
```

## How it looks like

[image: How it looks like]

## How it should look like

[image: How it should look like]

Does anybody know how to achieve the correct look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% per cent sure I understand what you want, but I don't think this is possible the way you want it. Generally CSS can't "go back" when laying out, i.e. you can't have the layout of an element be depended on the layout of a second element that comes after it.

That said you could probably get something similar by using table "shrink-wrapping". Place the items in a table with a small `width` such as `1px`. You'll need to have make sure the form items don't wrap (e.g. `white-space: nowrap`), then they will stretch the table to the width of the widest one.

Comment: I've accepted the answer. Anyway, it's no solution. It just tells that it's not possible. The solution with the table does only work with one liners.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are expecting -

Use [**CSS Calc function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
.field2{ display: block; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
#text2{
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PqJk6/4/)

Comment: Hello, sorry that's not what I'm looking for. The outer box should get the width of the widest .field and not vice versa. Take a look at my last screenshot. The width of the <input> did not change between them.